# What memory needs to be freed between videos played using gstreamer1

Tags: c, memory-leaks, gstreamer

I am using gstreamer1 in my program. I have four elements: filesrc, decodebin, autovideosink, autoaudiosink.

When a new pad on the decodebin gets added, it connects to the videosink or audiosink.

```
int display_video(char* path, GstInfo *gst_info){  
    if(!gst_info->pipeline)  
        return 0;  

    GstStateChangeReturn ret;
    g_object_set(gst_info->source, "location", path, NULL);
    ret = gst_element_set_state (gst_info->pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
    if (ret == GST_STATE_CHANGE_FAILURE) {
        g_printerr ("Unable to set the pipeline to the playing state.\n");
        gst_object_unref (gst_info->pipeline);
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;

}
```

This is how I start the video

```
static void display_video_eos (GstBus *bus, GstMessage *msg, DisplayInfo *dinfo) {
    gst_element_set_state(dinfo->ginfo->pipeline, GST_STATE_READY);    
    notify_rest_of_program();
}
```

I feel like there should be some resources that I free before calling display_video again. Once I start looping through this it leaks memory like mad. Any suggestions?

Comment: You might try stopping the pipeline before setting the new location.  Can you sketch out what other elements there are?

Comment: filesrc, decodebin, autovideosink, and autoaudiosink are the only elements I manually create. Doesn't `gst_element_set_state(dinfo->ginfo->pipeline, GST_STATE_READY);` stop the pipeline?

Comment: Each element interprets the states in its own way, but GST_STATE_NULL is more of the "clean things up" state.  I'd expect these sort of stop/start pipelines to leak over time because the under-the-hood workings can be so complex, but if it leaks memory "like mad" there is probably an issue somewhere in your code.  Try to post a larger snippet of your main loop.